# How to rotate an object defined by x y z points around the x y or z axis

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, geometry, coordinates

I'm working with a program where I visualize molecules. The molecules are represented by multiple x, y, and z values for each atom. What I would like to be able to do, is some math on each coordinate and have the resulting molecule be rotated on one of the axis. 
I've tried using these formulas:

`y' = y*cos q - z*sin q`

`z' = y*sin q + z*cos q`

`x' = x`

and the corresponding ones for Y and Z axis. In rotations of 180 degrees, the resulting molecule looks fine, but appears to be the enatiomer (mirror image). Any other angle (other than 360) skews the molecules apart from each other.

What I was hoping for was that all atoms would rotate "together". If it matters I'm working in Java.

Thank you for your help

edited code

```
if (axis == 'X') {
        // y' = y*cos q - z*sin q
        // z' = y*sin q + z*cos q
        // x' = x
        y = y * Math.cos(radians) - z * Math.sin(radians);
        z = y * Math.sin(radians) + z * Math.cos(radians);
    }
    else if(axis == 'Y'){
        //z' = z*cos q - x*sin q
        //x' = z*sin q + x*cos q
        //y' = y
        z = z * Math.cos(radians) - x * Math.sin(radians);
        x = z * Math.sin(radians) + x * Math.cos(radians);
    }
    else if(axis == 'Z'){
        //x' = x*cos q - y*sin q
        //y' = x*sin q + y*cos q 
        //z' = z
        x = x * Math.cos(radians) - y * Math.sin(radians);
        y = x * Math.sin(radians) + y * Math.cos(radians);
    }
```

edit 2. Found the error. I was calculating the first coordinate value correctly, and assigning it. When I attempt to calculate the second coordinate, I have changed the first coordinate and so get the wrong value for the second one. I'm sorry for the troubles

Comment: I redid the calculations using the rotation matrix and they are right, it might be something else in your code (did you remember to use **radians** to use the Java API trig functions?)

Comment: In second thought, the fact that you get the mirror image instead of the rotated one, makes me think that you are indeed using radians but you are rotating the wrong axis.

Comment: The formula is indeed correct for rotating two of the coordinates of a 3D point (rotation about an axis), problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @user2350616 Is this your project or can you use already built methods?

Comment: This is my code, no pre-built methods

Comment: @user2350616 In your code, all atoms share the x, y, z and radians values? I'm asking this because your implementation of the formula seems fine.

Comment: Each atom has a different x, y, and z value. But I wish to rotate them all to the same radian value.

Comment: All atoms share the same 3D space and so I think they share the same axis. Here is a picture that might help. http://imgur.com/MU30u38 I'm not sure I understand when you say "create a central x,y,z axis". How do I create an axis? I have a list of x, y, z coordinates for each atom. I want to go through this list, and rotate each atom, 1 by 1, and then be left with the same entire molecule, rotated by the value each atom was.

Comment: @user2350616 nevermind my last comment. After seeing the image I'm as lost as you are.

Comment: Wow. I discovered the problem. In my implementation, I execute the first line, get that coordinate correct, and assign the value to the coordinate. This means when I go to calculate the second coordinate value, I've already edited the first point and so my second calculation is always wrong. I'm sorry for the troubles

Comment: @user2350616 Awesome. Glad you figured it out. Sorry I didn't help much.

Comment: No worries and thanks you helped a lot. Small non-required side question. Do you know if there is a simple edit you can make to this formula, to rotate around another point, rather than the origin?

Comment: @user2350616 You mean a random point? No sorry can't help you there. You can check out Processing at processing.org and see how they implement their rotate() method. Processing is a programming language based on Java specifically made for artists. Its really easy to use especially for visualizations.

Comment: Do a translation so the new point becomes the origin (substract the point coordinates), rotate, and reverse the translation.

Comment: @user2350616: when you have found the answer to your question, feel free to post an answer yourself. I guess that the question will be closed in this case nevertheless, since the actual problem appears unrelated to the core of the question you asked, but remember this for future situations like this one.